# How to call a getter entrypoint in contract using completium-cli

Tags: archetype

How to call a getter entrypoint in contract using completium-cli? For example if it is declared like this:

```
variable bar : nat = 0
variable msg : string = ""

getter getBar(s : string) : nat {
  msg := s;
  return (bar + length(s))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using TS binding, it is quite straightforward as shown for example in the FA1.2:
https://github.com/completium/archetype-fa1/blob/main/tests/00-fa1.ts#L133

from the CLI, there is the `run_getter` command:

```
completium-cli run getter <GETTER_ID> on <CONTRACT_ALIAS|CONTRACT_ADDRESS> [--arg <MICHELSON_DATA>] [--as <CALLER_ADDRESS>]
```